# How to use SQL with Postgresql commands in Flask (Python) without SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, flask

How would I use Postgresql without SQLAlchemy in a Flask (Python) application? Any tutorial links, etc would be appreciated.

Comment: This question is off topic for SO. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `psycopg2` to communicate with a Postgres database. Issuing requests would be the same as straight SQL, however it also has support for prepared queries, off hand I don't remember the syntax it uses.

In terms of ensuring thread safety, I would create the connection and store it on `flask.g` so every request uses its own connection.